# Error when editing or saving

Tags: wordpress

When I would like to Edit and save data,When i save my changes it give me the error

> Error, Please try again.

appreciate from your response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have a definitive answer for you.

In lieu of that, be sure to update your WP core, all plugins and theme files to the latest versions. If there's any resent plugin additions try deactivating them, try the update again see if it's one of them that is affecting this action.

I would also recommend, you contact the theme provider/creator and see if they have a possible reason/solution for you.

As an aside: If you wanted to add the map to a page you can use the WP native editor. Add a google maps block, type in the address, it does the rest for you, no need to add the iframe code from Google.

GL and hope you are able to solve it!